# Adding a ComboBox control with multi selection in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, tfs-sdk, tfs-workitem

I'm trying to add a combobox with MultiSelect in my TFS and this [tutorial Codeplex](http://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Multivalue%20control&referringTitle=Home) is guiding me. After installing the Download file I have obtained the first error:

```
Could not find file 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Team Foundation\Work Item Tracking 
\Custom Controls\12.0\MultiValueControl.wicc'.
```

The description lack these two files in the folder. After installation I noticed that instead of the files go to folder were 12.0 to 14.0 folder (folder created with the installation). And I took the two files that were in the 14.0 folder and added in 12.0, they are;

> MultiValueControl.wicc
>
> CodePlex.WitCustomControls.dll

But now it has led me the error:

```
 Could not load file or assembly     
 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Controls, Version = 14.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b03f5f7f11d50a3a' 
 or one of its dependencies.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Custom Controls come with two kinds of files:

1. The Web Access extension for the Web portal of the TFS Server
2. The Visual Studio assembly that contains the controls for Visual Studio and Office.

The complexity is that the files you need depend on the versions of TFS **and** the version of Visual Studio.

For each version of Visual Studio on your system you need to download and install the work item control assembly for each version. The 14.0 version you mention is meant for Visual Studio 2015 and TFS 2015.

If your TFS is version 2013, you'll need to download an older version which supports version 12.0 to upload to the server.

And you need to dowload the version for **each** Visual Studio version:

- 14.0 for Visual Studio 2015
- 12.0 for Visual Studio 2013
- 11.0 for Visual Studio 2012
- 10.0 for Visual Studio 2010

The individual downloads can be found on the ["Downloads" page](http://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/releases/view/620316) and each version is listed in the Release Notes.

[image]

After installation you must register the Web Access control on the server's extension page which can be found in the server level settings. After selecting <kbd>Browse</kbd> point it to the 12.0 `CodePlex.WitCustomControls.MultiValueControl.zip` file on your local system and upload that to the server.

Be sure to clear the browser cache or <kbd>shift</kbd>+refresh the page in TFS web access so that the new Javascript files are loaded correctly.

[image]

(Screenshot from the 2015 version, but the page is almost identical to that of the 2013 version).